# What does this formula mean? What is the name of it?

Tags: percentages

I am writing here because I have my doubts about a formula
I was looking for a formula that provides me a range of number into percentage.

Let me explain what I mean.

1. I have a Minimun and a Maximum number in this case.
   $Min = 0$  and $Max = 45$
2. This is the formula I use to get the percentage between the min and max
   $ CurrentPercentage = \frac {Input - Min} {Max - Min}  $
3. The $ Input $ can be any number between $Min$ and $Max$

But now, I need a formula for the final result I'll try to explain.

let's say an example $Input = 22.5$ and $Output= 22.5$ which is 50% (0.5).

If the input is more than the $Max = 45 $ example $Input = 67.5$ the output should return like $Output = 22.5$

so my question is how should be my formula be like?
I am a bit curious if the formula has a name.

Edit:

If the input is more than the $Max = 45 $

$Input = 67.5$ the output Must return $Output = 22.5$ (0.5) not (1.5)

Comment: I don't know if the explicit formula you provided has a name, but the process is called "normalizing".

Comment: then your current percentage formula is wrong because in the 67.5-0 =67.5  and 67.5/45 = 1.5 not 0.5 so you might as well take the fractional part of it.

Comment: Ratio is a word that might fit.

Comment: @Zonko Or, perhaps, "normalizing".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I got them confused. Edited already.

Comment: Input=67.5 the output Must return Output=22.5 (0.5) not (1.5)